# Refering to two classes inside an Html tag using BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

hello im having an issue trying to get my `dom element` of a specific tag that has two `class`
let's have this example :

```
<a href="website" class="tab_item   app_impression_tracked >
</a>
```

I used as a code for finding elements inside my `<a>` tag

`containers = page_soup.find_all("a", {"class": "tab_item.app_impressions_tracked"})`

and as a result I get an empty variable which means it's not working, do you guys have any other alternative that can help me ? even the `css selector` didnt solve the problem

Comment: The page is probably loaded dynamically, so requests won't support it. Try using `selenium` as an alternative

Comment: Please share the URL.

Comment: here's the url `https://store.steampowered.com/tags/fr/RPG/`  , and i'm trying to get those games description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is loaded dynamically, therefore if we call `soup.prettify()`, you see that all the desired output is under the class `tab_item` which includes tags that we don't want,  and not under the class `tab_item   app_impression_tracked`.

A different approach would be to use a CSS Selector to find all links under the `NewReleasesRows` `ID` *(`<div id="NewReleasesRows">`)*.

To use a CSS Selector use the [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method instead of `find_all()` *(in your example you have used `find_all()` instead of `select()`)*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://store.steampowered.com/tags/fr/RPG/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select("#NewReleasesRows > a"):
    print(tag["href"])
```

Output:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/app/1433420/Hero_by_Chance/?snr=1_241_4_rpg_103
https://store.steampowered.com/app/1235140/Yakuza_Like_a_Dragon/?snr=1_241_4_rpg_103
https://store.steampowered.com/app/1445440/Blacksmith_of_the_Sand_Kingdom/?snr=1_241_4_rpg_103
...And on...
```

Comment: hello thank you for your help , I tried to loop  around  `top_tag` class while concatening all the value but I couldnt find a way to , can you help me to get all those tags?

Answer (score 0):

I would use css selectors for this:

```py
# You can chain classes together, css will match objects which satisfy both classes
# the added [href] specifies element must have an href
my_links = soup.select('a.tab_item.app_impression_tracked[href]')

# Get the hrefs for each one:
my_links_href = [x.get("href") for x in my_links]
```

Comment: This returns am empty list..See my above answer  for an explanation.

Comment: Are the "multiple classes" being interpreted as a single class with spaces? @MendelG